# php regex for finding image in a Text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

i have no idea about php regex i wish to extract all image tags `<img src="www.google.com/exampleimag.jpg">` form my html how can i do this using preg_match_all

thanks SO community for u'r precious time

well my scenario is like this there is not whole html dom but just a variable with img tag  `$text="this is a new text <img="sfdsfdimg/pfdg.fgh" > there is another iamh <img src="sfdsfdfsd.png"> hjkdhfsdfsfsdfsd kjdshfsd dummy text`

Comment: You just want all images, regardless what their `src` value is?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML; read up on DomDocument - http://www.php.net/domdocument

Comment: Use a PHP HTML parser instead of a regex.  HTML and regular expressions don't mix well.

Comment: @JonathanSampson do i need domdocument too when my scenario is as above

Comment: @spiderman I just tested your text, and it found the image just fine.

Comment: @JonathanSampson can please tell how can i get whole <image> tag using this approach

Comment: @spiderman Please see the latest addition to my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Instead, use something like the [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/domdocument) that exists for this very reason:

```
$html = 'Sample text. Image: <img src="foo.jpg" />. <img src="bar.png" />';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $html );

$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img");

for ( $i = 0; $i < $images->length; $i++ ) {
  // Outputs: foo.jpg bar.png
  echo $images->item( $i )->attributes->getNamedItem( 'src' )->nodeValue;
}
```

You could also get the image HTML itself if you like:

```
// <img src="foo.jpg" />
echo $doc->saveHTML ( $images->item(0) );
```

Answer (score 1):

[You can't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/477127). You're much better off using the DOM classes.  They make it trivially easy to extract the images from a valid HTML tree.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument ();
$doc -> loadHTML ($html);
$images = $doc -> getElementsByTagName ('img'); // This will generate a collection of DOMElement objects that contain the image tags
```